# Store NumPy Row and Column Headers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2 dimensional numpy array that contains the daily stock prices for multiple stocks. For example

```
daily_prices = np.array([  
    [4,3,3,1],  
    [5,4,3,6],  
    [6,3,2,7],  
    [3,9,7,4],  
    [8,4,6,3],  
    [8,3,3,9]])
```

where each row is a different date, and each column is a different stock.

I'd like to be able to store in array (or something more suitable), the names of the stocks going across (like 'MSFT', 'CSCO', 'GOOG', 'F') and the dates going down.

In other words, I want to name the rows and the columns like you would in a spreadsheet.

Is there a NumPythonic way to do this?

Comment: Definitely pandas as @ogrisel mentioned. It's aimed at exactly what you're doing. pandas.pydata.org

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays):

```
import numpy as np

daily_prices = np.array(
    [
        (4,3,3,1),
        (5,4,3,6),
        (6,3,2,7),
        (3,9,7,4),
        (8,4,6,3),
        (8,3,3,9)],
    dtype=[('MSFT','float'),('CSCO','float'),('GOOG','float'),('F','float') ]
    )
```

This allows you to access columns like this:

```
print(daily_prices['MSFT'])
# [ 4.  5.  6.  3.  8.  8.]
```

and rows like this:

```
print(daily_prices[2])
# (6.0, 3.0, 2.0, 7.0)
```

Comment: @idris: Yes, there are two packages (DataArrays and larry) which offer this capability. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910301/ndarray-field-names-for-both-row-and-column/3910961#3910961.

Comment: also the DataFrame.py class might be of interest to some. It is allegedly similar to the R DataFrame container. http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/DataFrame

Comment: There is also pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/ which implements the R DataFrame datastructure + many more feature (time series, automated alignment, joins, groupby, quick plots...).