# Assign column and row labels to merged numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have multiple arrays without column or row names, and I would like to combine them using something like `numpy.vstack()` or `numpy.hstack()`.

Column and row labels can be assigned can be done [when creating a structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795748/store-numpy-row-and-column-headers), but [hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) don't seem to have this functionality.

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a2 = np.array([5,6,7,8])
a3 = np.vstack([a1,a2],dtype=[('RowName1','double'),('RowName2','double')])
```

yielding:

```
TypeError: vstack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vstack` doesn't work with structured arrays, but only with 'standard' numpy arrays that are contiguous in memory. The easiest way is for you to create an empty structured array and then fill it up with the rows that you want:

```
import numpy as np
a3 = np.empty(4, dtype=[('RowName1','double'),('RowName2','double')])
a3['RowName1'] = a1
a3['RowName2'] = a2
```

Answer (score 2):

Something possible option is (since `recfunctions` are pretty hidden):

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions
a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4]).astype(('RowName1',float))
a2 = np.array([5,6,7,8]).astype(('RowName2',float))
recfunctions.merge_arrays((a1, a2))
```

---

Had this, but this has a few problems to be careful with, because of how reinterpretation of memory works with view, its better to just create a new recarray with the concatenated array.

you could just turn around the logic:

```
import numpy    
a1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
a2 = np.array([5,6,7,8])
# ok, not that beautiful. But if your arrays are the correct type to begin with
# you can skip that astype call. Using `np.c_[]` since it happens to concatenate right.
a3 = np.c_[v1,v2].astype(float).copy('C').view(dtype=[('RowName1',float),('RowName2',float)])
```

Comment: I don't think that works as the OP wanted. First, it will view integer arrays as double (ie, garbled), and it will have the wrong shape because the wanted index is by row and not by column.

Comment: @tiango, right :/... I didn't check that `vstack` wasn't really right to begin with, and without explicit cast to the right type, the view is bad of course.

Comment: it still gives a wrong result. If you look at your `a3['RowName1']`, it gives a 2D array: `array([[ 1.,  5.], [ 3.,  7.]])`. I'm not trying to criticise your answers, just genuinely curious. Even if `a1`, `a2` are of the same type and concatenated in the right direction, it doesn't seem possible to get a view per row -- the shape is wrong.

Comment: @tiango yeah sorry, it was not a good idea with view. The reason is that the concatenation array is not C-Contiguous and `view` only reinterprets the underlying memory, but because it is not C-Contiguous that is not the same as the wanted result... Its actually a good example why one needs to be careful with `view`...

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider looking at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).  Pandas has a nice [data frame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) data structure that might be good.

Of course, this requires you to add another dependency to your project.  Luckily, if you are already using numpy then Pandas is pretty easy to get going.